# UNMET peer dependency after installing 2nd dependency

Tags: react-native

I am struggling to set up an environment, could someone take a look at these errors and let me know what they mean?

Thank you, I appreciate it more than you know.

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@>=17.0.1, required by react-native-web@0.17.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@>=17.0.1, required by react-native-web@0.17.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-native-gesture-handler@>= 1.5.0, required by react-navigation-stack@2.10.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-native-screens@>=1.0.0 || >= 2.0.0-alpha.0 || >= 2.0.0-beta.0 || >= 2.0.0, required by react-navigation-stack@2.10.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-navigation@^4.1.1, required by react-navigation-stack@2.10.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`peer dep missing` means there are packages you have installed that depend on those missing dependencies to function properly. react-navigation-stack, for instance depends on a few other packages of which react-navigation is a core dependency to have. If react-navigation is not installed, react-navigation-stack will flag react-navigation as a missing dependency.

To fix this try one or all of the following till your issue is fixed

Go to your project level android directory and run `./gradlew clean` then try building the project

If the problem persists, delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install` again to pull the required dependencies

If that doesn't work, run `npm list` and then resolve all `UNMET DEPENDENCY` issues by installing any dependency with the `peer dep missing` flag

Comment: How do I go about doing the last part? I tried manually installing the ones it mentions, but it did not solve anything

Comment: Go to the root directory of your project and run npm list, this will list all the dependencies that project requires to run properly, note the ones with unmet dep and install them manually, then ./gradlew clean